# Excel - Summarize in text

Tags: excel

In the spreadsheet below, I have no problem summing the numbers. What I need, however, is a string which I can input into our time recording system (so I can just cut and paste it over). I want to ignore descriptions for buckets which have no time allocated on that day. The bottom row in the image is an example of what I need, but how can I get this to happen automatically in Excel? (assuming that the range having the data in will always be B3:F8)

[image]

Comment: This is problematic.  Let's take Tuesday for example.  How does Excel know the difference between Writing (0.5 hours), Arithmetic (0.5 hours), and Software Development (0.5 hours)?  If Tuesday just had a single 0.5, how would Excel know which bucket you meant?  Right now the only thing denoting which is which is the row it's on.  This is a good solution, so I'm not sure why you want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the formula you can try:

```
=IF(B3="","",$H3&" ("&B3&"hrs)")&IF(B4="","",CHAR(10)&$H4&" ("&B4&"hrs)")&IF(B5="","",CHAR(10)&$H5&" ("&B5&"hrs)")&IF(B6="","",CHAR(10)&$H6&" ("&B6&"hrs)")&IF(B7="","",CHAR(10)&$H7&" ("&B7&"hrs)")&IF(B8="","",CHAR(10)&$H8&" ("&B8&"hrs)")
```

I heard there is a `TEXTJOIN` funciton in Excel 2016 that can do the same work quickly but unfortunately I don't have it with me.  But anyway, try this formula and let me know.

Comment: Thank you! Gets me well on the way to a solution! Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome.  Just the formula itself is so ugly that I didn't really like.  Haha.  But anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to have gaps in the rows for unused buckets? If so, then assuming your first data row is row 3, something like =IF (B3>0, $H3 & "(" & B3 & " hrs)", "") and copy that to all your "summary" cells (though there's no actual summing taking place). If not, then the only way I can think of involves VBA code...